# Discord.py Music Bot problem with FFmpeg on heroku

Tags: heroku, ffmpeg, discord.py

I'm coding my first music bot for discord and successfully tested it on the localhost. After that, I moved it on Heroku and installed FFmpeg buildpack for it. But for some reason, it doesn't work.
Here is proof that I installed FFmpeg buildpack on Heroku: [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tugqe.png)

Here is my code (that works well on localhost):

```
youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''

ytdl_format_options = {
'format': 'bestaudio/best',
'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
'restrictfilenames': True,
'noplaylist': True,
'nocheckcertificate': True,
'ignoreerrors': False,
'logtostderr': False,
'quiet': True,
'no_warnings': True,
'default_search': 'auto',
'source_address': '0.0.0.0'
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn'
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)

class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
    super().__init__(source, volume)

    self.data = data

    self.title = data.get('title')
    self.url = data.get('url')

@classmethod
async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
    loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
    data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))

    if 'entries' in data:
        data = data['entries'][0]

    filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
    return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)

@client.command()
async def join(ctx):
channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
if ctx.voice_client is not None:
    return await ctx.voice_client.move_to(channel)
await channel.connect()

@client.command()
async def play(ctx, *, URL):
    async with ctx.typing():
        player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url)
        ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)
    await ctx.send('Now playing: {}'.format(player.title))
```

Comment: Hey Phantom, would it be possible for you to provide the traceback? It'll help with narrowing down the issue.

Comment: @Diggy. Yes, do you have a discord?

Comment: Yep. Diggy#0649

Comment: @Diggy. I added you